# Format pen drive on windows 7

Tags: usb-drive

While injecting pen drive into computer, it suggests to format pen drive. When I am trying to format, it shows windows was unable to complete the format.

The drive info:

- BitLocker status : Not Encryptable.
- Used space 0 bytes, free space 0 bytes.
- File system unknown.

I tried by using AOMEI and M3 Data recovery software, but didn't work. So what can be the solution to format pen drive?

Comment: @UltraCommit I didn't do anything with BitLocker and file system in disk management shows RAW.

Answer (score 0):

Format the pen-drive in Disk Management.